# i m trying to redirect one JSP page to another along with the input text value

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

Page1.JSP

```
//input text box
Enter Form id:<input type="text" name="formID" id="formID" > 
<a href='Page2.jsp?formID=<%=request.getParameter("formID")%>' value="View Form" name="displayForm">Show Form</a>
```

This returns a null value. In page2. JSP

```
//get the input value
<%String formsubmitID=request.getParameter("formID");%>
```

This returns null. I am not able to parse. I tried all the methods using `window.location`, adding a button adding a `href` link but i am not able to access the input text field and redirect both at the same time. Here is the code for first JSP Page from which I need to redirect to another JSP Page with the input text field entered at Firest JSP Page.

I tried using a button and redirect in Java script

```
//javascript for redirecting to another page
function redirect(elem){
  alert("in redirect Method:")
  elem.setAttribute("action","Page2.jsp");
  elem.submit();
  return false;
}
// Page1.JSP 
<form ACTION="Page2.jsp" METHOD="POST" onload='onload()'>
  Enter Form id:<input type="text" name="formID" id="formID"/>
  <INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT" value="Submit" onclick="redirect(this);">
</form>
```

This also doesn't work. Redirect doesn't happen at all when I am using `window.location.href` or `window.location`.

Please help me find the solution for the same.

Comment: you can get value var name = document.getElementById("formID").value; and redirect to page2 like this window.location = "page2.jsp?formID="+name;. First situation is null because jsp generated with initial value(null) for input. Even though you put text in input, it is not caught changes on DOM by jsp.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using form than whenever you click on button you will be directed to Page2.jsp (i.e. url mentioned in form action) like

```
<form ACTION="Page2.jsp">
Enter Form id:<input type="text" name="formID" id="formID"/>
<INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT" value="Submit">
</form>
```

In Page2.jsp get value of text field like

```
<%String formsubmitID=request.getParameter("formID");%>
```